# Find number of  trials of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability

The probability of a man hitting the target is 1/4, how many times he should shoot so that his probability of hitting the target at least once becomes 3/4.

Comment: What is the probability that he does not hit the target at all in $n$ tries? As a function of $n$, I mean.  And how is this related to the probability that he hits the target at least once on these same $n$ tries?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: Let $E_n$ denote the event that the a man will shoot the target at least once after $n$ trials.

- Find the probability of the complement of $E_n$, assuming shootings are independent.
- Compute $\mathbb{P}(E_n)$ from $\mathbb{P}(E_n^c)$
- Determine for which $n$ you would have $\mathbb{P}(E_n) > \frac{3}{4}$.